# Data structures for parsed sentence

Tags: java, parsing, tree, nlp

Please find an example sentence:

```
(S1 (S (S (NP (NP (NP (NN Activation)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NN protein) (NN kinase) (NN C)))) (CC and) (NP (NP (NN elevation)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NN cAMP))))) (VP (VBP interact) (ADVP (RB synergistically)) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB raise) (NP (NP (NP (NP (NN c-Fos)) (CC and) (NP (NN AP-1))) (NN activity)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NN Jurkat) (NNS cells))))))))) (. .)))
```

The objective is create a tree from this sentence; the leaves are the words, the intermediate nodes are the Part of speech tags, and the root is S1. The parenthesis indicate the span of the phrases contained within the sentence; they need not be included in the tree.

What would be a good combination of data-structures to achieve the above objective, and would you also be able to share the pseudo-code which supports your suggestion?

I have in mind a HashMap and ArrayList, but am confused how to actually begin with the implementation. Just that the logic isn't coming intuitively to me at this point. Your suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the question what is a good data structure for the tree, or how should this string be represented before it turns into tree form?

Comment: Yes, it is, how can this string be represented so that the result is a tree form.

Comment: Why not turn it directly into tree form while parsing it?

Comment: Would you be able to share with a direct tree form implementation?

Comment: From this one example I see that each node is tagged with a part of speech and contains either a word (leaf node) or one or more children. How complicated you make the classes composing the tree depends on the operations you need to perform on it.

Comment: Well, the operation needed is to iterate through the NounPhrases (NP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar in Python recently.  I'll address just the part about data structures:

Each part of speech is either a list of parts of speech (a non-terminal), or just a single word (a terminal).  So you could create classes something like:

```
enum Type {
    Sentence,
    NounPhrase,
    VerbPhrase,
    Conjunction,
    ...
};

interface PartOfSpeech { };

class NonTerminal implements PartOfSpeech {
    Type type;
    List<PartOfSpeech> subparts;
};

class Terminal implements PartOfSpeech {
    String word;
};
```

This is relatively untyped: your program needs to construct only valid strutures of these (e.g. no making a VerbPhrase consisting of a list of Sentences -- you can do it but it's meaningless!).

The alternative route is to define a more explicit type system.  So you could define classes for each type of part of speech, e.g.

```
class VerbPhrase {
    Verb verb;
    AdverbPhrase adverb; /* optional */
    ...
};
```

Since there are several ways of making a verb phrase, you could instead have classes for each type:

```
interface VerbPhrase { };

class IntransitiveVerbPhrase implements VerbPhrase {
    Verb verb;
    AdverbPhrase adverb; /* optional */
};

class TransitiveVerbPhrase implements VerbPhrase {
    Verb verb;
    AdverbPhrase adverb; /* optional */
    NounPhrase obj;
};
```

And so on.  The optimal degree of type explicitness at the Java level might not be obvious at the outset.  Start by writing something that handles simple sentences, and see how it feels.

In my case I created classes for each part of speech type, though each inherits from either a Terminal or Nonterminal.  Then I have rules for how you can construct each type.  This got kind of messy for some of them, e.g.

```
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Noun])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [RelativeNounWord])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Noun, AdjectiveClause])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Article, Noun])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Article, Adjectives, Noun])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Article, Noun, AdjectiveClause])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Article, Adjectives, Noun, AdjectiveClause])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Adjectives, Noun])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Adjectives, Noun, AdjectiveClause])
add_rule(NounPhrase, [Article, Adjectives, Noun])
...
```

That's code for saying, "a NounPhrase is a Noun.  Or, it's a RelativeNoun.  Or, it's a Noun followed by an AdjectiveClause.  Or, etc.".  There's a general parser which attempts to apply rules to a list of words until it gets a tree.  (You can see the messy and undocumented code at http://code.google.com/p/ejrh/source/browse/trunk/ircbot/nl.py .)

There's a certain amount of combinatorial explosion here.  It could possibly be improved by introducing new types of parts of speech, or just making some parts of it as optional: intead of having a rule for every possible combination of Article/Adjectives/AdjectiveClause/etc. present/absent, you could just make them optional.

Comment: wow! I've thrown myself into deep waters here; hadn't anticipated it. Thank you for sharing your suggestion; will need to spend sometime in understanding it.

Comment: The code probably reflects that I was playing with various ideas and hacking them in there without thinking too much about architecture.  You're probably a bit more serious about it than me. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The basic approach for this kind of thing is to *lex* the string into a sequence of *tokens*, and then *parse* that string into what's called an *abstract syntax tree*. This is a large topic, but very briefly:

*Lexing* means breaking your string down into different logical tokens. In your case, you probably just want a sequence broken into open and close parentheses, and labels. So your token is one of "(", ")", or a sequence of non-whitespace characters that isn't that.

*Parsing* means reading that sequence of characters and building the tree structure out of it.

First you need a tree structure: in your case it's probably a data structure that consists of a `Sentence` that consists of a part-of-speech tag and a list of objects that can be either words or subsentences. (I'm assuming no interesting structure here: if you know that NN can only contain words and NP can only contain subsentences, or something like that, you can make a richer tree structure here.)

Next you need to parse your tokens into this tree. The easiest ways to do this are pretty simple: for instance, it looks like here you can just write a function `parse(List tokens) that expects the first token to be an open parenthesis and the second to be a label, and then recursively consumes tokens from the sequence until it encounters a close-parenthesis token.

These topics are the subject of giant books and many libraries and so on, but hopefully this will get you started enough to have an idea of how to approach the problem.

Comment: This has helped me decide on using subsentences as the leaves of the tree, instead of words. Tags like NP, VP, and such (ending in P) are phrasal tags. Thank you for touching on certain critical points.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very naive implementation to get you started with some ideas. It has no typing based on part of speech, nor does it enforce any rules beyond what I could infer from the single example.

```
class Node {
    String partOfSpeech;

    Node(String partOfSpeech) {
        this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
    }

    String toString() {
        return "(" + partOfSpeech + " " + getInternalString() + ")";
    }

    abstract String getInternalString(); // could use a better name
    abstract String toSentence();
}

class Word extends Node {
    String word;

    Word(String partOfSpeech, String word) {
        super(partOfSpeech);
        this.word = word;
    }

    String getInternalString() {
        return word;
    }

    String toSentence() {
        return word;
    }
}

class Phrase extends Node {
    List<Node> children;

    Phrase(String partOfSpeech) {
        super(partOfSpeech);
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    add(Node child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    String getInternalString() {
        return combineChildren(false);
    }

    String toSentence() {
        return combineChildren(true);
    }

    private String combineChildren(boolean sentence) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Node child : children) {
            sentenct.append(sentence ? child.toSentence() : child.toString()).append(' ');
        }
        return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
    }
}
```